# SQL-join two tables

Tags: sql

I have two table

```
tab1:
mothcode, bAmt
FY2016-01 100
FY2016-02 200
FY2016-03 300

tab2:
mothcode, bAmt
FY2016-02 200
FY2016-04 400
FY2016-05 500
FY2016-06 600
```

I want the result table is

```
monthcode bAmt sAmt
FY2016-01 100
FY2016-02 200
FY2016-03 300
FY2016-02      200
FY2016-04      400
FY2016-05      500
FY2016-06      600
```

Comment: And your problem doing it is ?

Comment: Can you prove that you did anything? Any tries? Example query that failed to retrieve the result?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this:

```
SELECT mothcode, bAmt, NULL AS sAmt
FROM tab1

UNION ALL

SELECT mothcode, NULL AS bAmt, bAmt AS sAmt
FROM tab2
```